# Reading from the socket and then dividing the input string is behaving not in a normal way in C

Tags: c

I am reading a message from the socket using this tcp_read function:

```
    ssize_t tcp_read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)
    {
        size_t nread = 0;

        while (count > 0) {
        int r = read(fd, buf, count);
        if (r < 0 && errno == EINTR)
            continue;
        if (r < 0)
            return r;
        if (r == 0)
            return nread;
        buf = (unsigned char *) buf + r;
        count -= r;
    nread += r;
    }

    return nread;
}
```

In the server.c file I am creating a guessing the word game, I am reading the message from the user using this **tcp_read** function which is close to the real **read()**.

The user will input something like: "L: someword\r\n" and I am reading this in the following way:

```
   char read[strlen(token2)+5];
   char *token2 = "someword"
   int n = tcp_read(cfd, read, strlen(token2)+5);
   read[n] = '\0';

   char *s;
   size_t len = strlen(read);
   s = malloc(len);
   strcpy(s, read+3);  //to cut 'R: '
   s[len - 4] = 0; 
   tcp_write(cfd, s, strlen(s));

   if(strcmp(token2, read) == 0)
   {
         tcp_write(cfd, beg_o, strlen(beg_o)); 
   }else
   {
         tcp_write(cfd, beg_f, strlen(beg_f));
   }
```

**token2** is the word that the user is supposed to guess. and **beg_o** and **beg_f** are just some printing of 'Congratulation' and 'You failed'.

I did the strlen(token2) + 5, since the token2 is the word that the user should guess + 5 characters for 'R' ':' ' ' '\r' '\n', since those 5 characters are always the same every user inputs like this, only **someword** is what is dynamic.

**In the first iteration its working, but then when the function is called again it is not working anymore** (Because the second part of the code is in a big loop)

But I cannot understand why this is not working, sometimes it works sometimes it fails for example the user inputs **"L: someword\r\n"** and the read in my function is not **someword** but sometimes is **somew** sometimes is just **so**. It is behaving weird.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that compiles, just looking at it. The dynamic array dims are an extension, which you should probably avoid -- just do `char read[1024]` or something. (Really you should use a `#define` for that.) But in any case, `token2` is not even defined on the first line, so I don't see how the dynamic array dim can be evaluated.

Once you get over that, use a debugger. Step through line by line examining variables until you see where it's gone wrong.

Comment: I have a sentence as input which I tokenize using strtok() and then I pick one of the tokens randomly and save the string in token2, so token2 is just a 'char* token2;*. But for the sake of keeping it short in StackOverflow I only posted the part which I am having the problem with. The code which you see in the second part is a part of a way more bigger function!

Comment: If you can post a compilable sample folks may be more able to help. Anyway, first thing I'd do in your situation is print buf and the return value right after calling `tcp_read()`. If it's always OK there, then the problem is in your main code; if it's already wrong, then your problem is in `tcp_read`. And so on. Divide and conquer. (Also, if I were you, I'd make sure buf is always null-terminated on return from `tcp_read()`).

Comment: tcp_read() is always returning the correct input which the user is inserting, I checked it. In the first time the input like "K: someword\r\n" the s = "someword" which is correct, but when I call the function for the second time for another input like "K: someotherword" the s becomes s = ": someotherwor". (token2 is being updatet and I also check it every time it is coorect, also the input is correct, so I am only suspecting on the char*s but I cannot see any errors there)

Comment: OK, so step through in a debugger. Is `n` always correct? Does `len==n` always? (In fact you shouldn't have to recompute the strlen). What is `s` after the strcpy? After chopping it with the null? There's not that many places it could be going wrong. (You can debug the whole thing with `printf`s too, just print *everything*, but it'll be easier to find the bug with a debugger.) You'll get it!

Answer (score 0):

Don't return when `r == 0`. Wait until you reach `count` and return only then.